# program hangs when no more data from input stream

Tags: java, input, streaming

I am writing the front end to a chess engine (Stockfish). The engine is written in C++ so my program runs the executable stockfish.exe. I then need to give command line instructions to the engine and retrieve its output. The code i have successfully gets the output from the first instruction that i send ("uci") and prints this out to the java system output. Thats great but the program then hangs in this while loop on the readLine because the output from the engine has finished and no null string has been encountered. So the line that prints "done" never gets executed.
   Any ideas on how to workaround this greatly appreciated.

```
      public static void main(String args[]) {
       String line = "";
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("d://Stockfish/stockfish-  7-win/Windows/stockfish7.exe");
            Process pr = pb.start();

            String[] cmd = new String[2];

            cmd[0] = "uci" ;  
            cmd[1] = "isready" ;

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(pr.getOutputStream()) ;

            InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()) ;

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(stream);

            writer.println(cmd[0]) ;  
            writer.flush() ;

            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);                   
                System.out.println("got to here") ;
            }

            System.out.println("done") ;



            writer.println(cmd[1]) ;  
            writer.flush() ;
```

Comment: what issue do you have?

Comment: What is stockfish outputting? Perhaps there is no new line and you would be better of piping the output to a file. Then you can read the file into your java program.

Comment: I really need the program to be as interactive as possible - eventually i will process the engine output on a displayed board rather than printing it to the screen - so i dont think diverting to a file will work for me